# How to remove water mark in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, license

I installed Window 8 using an original Product Key then installed Windows Media Centre by entering a pirated key.

Now I am getting a message to activate my Windows again and a water mark is appearing on my desktop. Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Reinstall Windows using the original key.

Comment: @ROCK, your question was closed do to it appearing that you where asking advice on how to get away with piracy. If you your real goal was to remove Windows Media Center and only use what you legally can use please re-word your question to say that and it can be re-opened.

Comment: Call M$ and beg for forgiveness.

Answer (score 3):

When you installed Win8 Media center the new key took the place of your prior win8 key.

You can attempt reactivating over the phone if you still have your original key. To get to the phone activation menu, run: slui.exe 4

Or re-install and use your original key

Comment: That jumps past the product key, so you can't actually use this method if the key is borked. The answer I gave lets changing the product key, which he needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using `slmgr.vbs` you can re-install your original product key without having to reinstall Windows. You will need to reactivate afterwards of course. Open a `Command Prompt` as an Administrator and run:

```
cscript slmgr.vbs /ipk old-product-key
```

I believe it will want you to reboot to make it kick in. Then reactivate.

Comment: to clarify: if you are not in windows\system32 change to that directory before running; that's where slmgr.vbs is located.

Comment: "Using slmgr.vbs you can re-install your original product key without having to reinstall Windows." – Are you sure that's true in this case? Win8 with Media Centre is technically a completely different edition of Windows. Removing the Media Centre pack is actually not all that easy as simply entering the original Win8 key, which will most likely be rejected. Try it and see.